# Convert.ToInt32("example") Collisions?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

Will the C# function Convert.ToInt32(text) convert different words to the same int?  Any links or pushes in the right direction are appreciated!

P.S.
What about anagrams?

Comment: Depends on what you consider a word. Leading zeros don’t change the value of a number. As for anagrams: are 501 and 105 the same number in base 10?

Comment: Have you actually tried it with a word?

Comment: *Converts the specified string representation of a number to an equivalent 32-bit signed integer.* How can `"example"` be a *representation of a number*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `Convert.ToInt32(text)` will just try to parse your text to an `int`, like:

`Convert.ToInt32("032")` will return `32` as `int` but

`Convert.ToInt32("Brian")` will throw an exception.

I assume that you want to have some kind of hashing, when you say "different words to the same int".

Try `GetHashCode()`. It will return the same value if you call it multiple times with the same value, for example:

`"Brian".GetHashCode()` will always return `1635321435`

Comment: I imagine they’re using `Convert.ToInt32(word, 36)`.